# vba crashing on old data access methods

Tags: vba, db2

I have built up loads of data tools over the years for reading writing and updating data on the as400 (usually bulk updates)
After about 2014 all the ones that pulled in data using the rs.fields(index) method are all crashing now, but I can see very little on the web about it.
a very simple example is the following:

```
Function UserconnArray() As Boolean
    Dim CommString As String
    s = "username"
    t = "password"    
    CommString = "select field from table"

    Dim wb As String
    wb = "SystemNAme or IP"

    Dim c As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cm As New ADODB.Command
    On Error GoTo endpgm
    c.Open "Driver=Client Access ODBC Driver (32 bit);" & _
    "SYSTEM=" & wb & ";QueryTimeOut=0;UID=" & s & ";PWD=" & t & ";" & _
    "BLOCKFETCH=0;"
    cm.ActiveConnection = c
    cm.CommandText = CommString


    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cm.Execute()
    If rs.EOF Then GoTo endpgm


    If Not rs.EOF Then

    Cells(2, 2).Value = rs.Fields(0)
    UserconnArray = True

    End If

    c.Close

    Exit Function

endpgm:

'no data or error routine

UserconnArray = False

End Function
```

Anyone have any idea whats changed to make this type of code crash?
Oh and Ive put the Microsoft active objects in, as Ive said, I had hundreds of these all working until 2014(ish)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What do you mean with "crash"? Do you get an error? What kind of error? Where does it occur?

Comment: No, no error, the application just hangs.

Comment: I hadn't finished sorry. I first noticed it when I was running windows 7 office 2010. I then noticed it happened on widows 7 with office 2013.

Comment: lol really sorry I keep hitting enter for new line! I had really thought Id never be able to use them again. I had authored some really useful stuff with vba, but anything that had to read data via recordset wasn't working any longer (I hadn't had as much call to use them as in the past, but still, nice to have them if you need them). but literally 15 minutes ago I just noticed that it is working again on windows 10 office 2016!